# TFS - VsTest fail when all tests passed

Tags: tfs, vstest

When i run VsTset via TFS build sometimes is failed with the error:
"
An exception occurred while invoking executor `executor://mstestadapter/v2`: Could not find a part of the path `C:\Agents\CIAgents\Agent1\_work\s\TestResults\Deploy_[user] [date] [time]\In\\[machine_name]`

When i run the build few more times it passes without errors

Comment: trace agent logs, maybe another issues affect

Comment: Is this the exact path of the error because you should have a number between the _work and the s like _work\2\s if not then it's saving your test result as the root of the system (not in one specific workspace) and that could be the cause of your issue.

Comment: yes its _work/1/s/